# Python3 modules: path discrepancy

Tags: python, macos

I'm on Mac 10.8.5

I tried to locate os.py with python3 from Terminal:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py'
>>>
```

But when I try to locate it in Mac with Finder and Copy the full path I get this:

```
/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC/Plug-ins/MAXON CINEWARE AE/(CINEWARE Support)/bin/resource/modules/python/res/Python.osx.framework/lib/python2.6
```

I must have did something wrong with other programs in the past...

How can I solve this and put python3 in the correct path, so out from After Effects ?

Ths for your help.

Comment: I recommend you use pyenv. You can install pyenv from [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) and then install python 3.6 like this: `pyenv install 3.6.3` and then you can set it like global or make a virtualenv with pyenv virtualenv.

Comment: I will Thx for that. But how could I solve the path problem? How can I move python path to the 'correct place' ?

Comment: You can check the python that you use with `which python`. And the another thing that you can do and share is: `echo $PATH`. I don't know how you have gotten the path of "after effects" but the better thing is use `which python`

Comment: I did and double checked and I realize that actually there is a python folder into that plug in. SOLVED